# Question about a recursion example, i understand the code, and the program runs ok, but it doesn't run like i expect it to

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks for stopping by. So I've been learning about recursion on w3schools.com, and everything made sense, until I looked at the example they gave :

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

I understand everything in the code but this:
why is the result like this:

```
Recursion Example Results
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

In the sense of, why are the numbers listed from small to big?

OOhhh...actually, you know what? While writing this I think I understand now...
It's kinnda like 6+(5+(4+(3+(2+(1+(0)))))) right?
And that's why it types out the small ones first, from the 'deepest' recursion...
Interesting.
But now another question comes up:

```
else
  result = 0
return result
```

So essentially:

```
return 0
```

Right?
Then why does the program not print `0`or`None`?
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: To answer the question you didn't answer yourself.. Because 0 is the base case. At your innermost part of the function `k` will equal `1` and you're essentially calling `tri_recursion(k - 1)` or `tri_recursion(0)`. it returns `0` and adds it to `k` or `1` and that is your first `print` statement.

Comment: Also it won't work for values `k > ~996` because of the maximum stack depth - `sys.setrecursionlimit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already answered your first question yourself (by the way, it's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question as an answer here, for the benefit of others who may have a similar problem in the future), here's an answer to your second question:

The `return` statement is outside of the `if`-`else` clauses. So it returns whatever the result currently is, regardless of the above condition.

To get a better feeling for how this works, try to follow the flow of execution for two different calls of the function:

1. `tri_recursion(0)` calls the function with `k=0`. This means the `if`-condition is false, so the following indented code block (two lines here) is skipped, and the else statement is executed instead. So the value 0 is assigned to `result`. Nothing is printed, because there is no `print` statement here. Then the function returns `result`, which is 0 here.
2. `tri_recursion(1)` calls the function with `k=1`. This means the `if`-condition is true, so the following indented code block gets executed. So `result` gets the value `1 + tri_recursion(0)`, which includes the function call that takes us to point 1 above. After everything under 1. has happened, the function has returned 0, so `result` is now `1 + 0` = 1. We move on to the next line, which prints `result`, so it prints 1. The `else` clause is skipped, because the condition had been found to be true above. The function returns `result`, which is still 1.

In general, when you are struggling to understand the flow of execution, especially with recursive functions as in this example, it's often more helpful to have the `print()` calls at the beginning and end of the function, not somewhere in the middle. And especially with recursive functions or other nested function calls, we may cleverly add some space characters to highlight the hierarchy and see more readily which return value belongs to which function call:

```py
def tri_recursion(k):
    print('    ' * (6 - k) + 'calling tri_recursion() with k =', k)  

    if(k > 0):
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    else:
        result = 0

    print('    ' * (6 - k) + 'returning', result)
    return result

print('Recursion Example Results\n')
tri_recursion(6)
```

```py
Recursion Example Results

calling tri_recursion() with k = 6
    calling tri_recursion() with k = 5
        calling tri_recursion() with k = 4
            calling tri_recursion() with k = 3
                calling tri_recursion() with k = 2
                    calling tri_recursion() with k = 1
                        calling tri_recursion() with k = 0
                        returning 0
                    returning 1
                returning 3
            returning 6
        returning 10
    returning 15
returning 21

21
```

Comment: Right, but the ```result``` by then ```=0```, so just like you said, regardless of condition above it should print out ```0``` should it not? Or am I not getting something? Or, here is another point of view: so lets say it is outside of ```if - else``` just like you said, it doesn't see the conditions that set the value of ```result```, so for return ```result``` has no value so shouldn't it print out ```None```?

Comment: Sorry if my questions/thoughts are very very off, I'm just starting to get into python,(actively studied it for maybe a month), so I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of this, and even though I repeatedly look at the definition of ```return``` and seem to understand it, I still constantly get the feeling that I am waaaay off with my understanding of this, when I look at how people use this statement and what it actually does in the code.

Comment: No worries @GotABitCraaazy - I have expanded my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest, i do understand the flow of the functions, and I totally agree with you that ```print``` at the start and the end  helps, but what i think truly stops me from getting all of this is not really understanding the definition of ```return``` although everything i find gives quite a clear one... is ```return``` more like ```print out the value given after or if there is none print "None"``` Or is it more like```take the value of the variable specified later and update it everywhere to that value``` or is it``` take the value and store it, then use it when called upon```

Comment: Also, at your `console` or where the results are printed, the very last ```21```, I don't see a ```print(result)``` in your code, is that smth you added to the output or is that the```return``` working?

Comment: @GotABitCraaazy what effect the return statement ultimately has depends on the line of code that includes the function call. Think of it this way: Once a return statement is reached within the function, the execution of the function is terminated and the value given after `return` replaces the function call in the line of code that included the function call. When you're running a script and one line has a function call but nothing else (in particular, no assignment), the return value has no effect, unless this is the last line of the script, in which case the return value may be printed.

Comment: So in my output above, the last 21 is the return value given by the function call in the last line of the script. It would not show up in the output if that call had not been in the last line. This behavior may depend on your environment.

Comment: So basically you are saying that every code runs slightly different in every IDE, so everyone has to customize the code a little bit? Also, the ```return``` functions differently in each piece of code so more tweaking is needed there and to understand how it works or make it work like i need it to i need to toss it around in the code for some time, right?

Comment: No, the comment about the behavior perhaps depending on the environment was only referring to whether the expression *in the last line* of any script gets printed or not. And yes, trying out different places for the return statement (and also for the function call) is a good way to understand it.

Comment: Thank You Very Much!